# How to Solve Azure DataLakeStore File Content-Disposition Added in file?

Tags: c#, rest, api, azure, azure-data-lake

I was Uploaded Text file or image file or Zip File to Azure Data Lake Store. it' was Uploaded Successfully. But, before added some content in file.
I was Uploaded a File using Rest API. (Uploaded file using HttpClient in C#)

this Type of Content Added in

> ---b8b2dfc6-6128-43b5-8fb8-022820aedf02
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data;
> name=file1; filename=tick.txt; filename*=utf-8''tick.txt

If the Content Added So, The Image file and zip files are Not Open in Viewer/Explore.

How To Remove this type of header added in file From Upload.Here I shared my file uploaded code.

```
public object UploadFile(string srcfile, string destFilePath, bool force = true)
{
  var uploadurl = string.Format(UploadUrl, _datalakeAccountName, destFilePath);
  var stream = File.OpenRead(srcfile);
  HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accesstoken.access_token);
      using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
          formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file1", Path.GetFileName(srcfile));
           var response = client.PutAsync(uploadurl, formData).Result;
           return new { Status = response.StatusCode, Message = response.ReasonPhrase, details = response.ToString() };
         }
   }
 }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @mjwills  I was Uploaded a file using Rest API to Azure Data Lake Above content Added in File So, Not Open Image and Zip File. If i was Manually remove only open the File. How to Solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have try to use the following code, it works correcly on my side.

```
 public object UploadFile(string srcfile, string destFilePath, bool force = true)
    {
        var uploadurl = string.Format(UploadUrl, _datalakeAccountName, destFilePath);
        var stream = File.OpenRead(srcfile);
        HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new
                AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",  _accesstoken.access_token);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders
                .Accept
                .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
            var response = client.PutAsync(uploadurl, fileStreamContent).Result;

            return new { Status = response.StatusCode, Message = response.ReasonPhrase, details = response.ToString() };
        }
    }
```